# Send RPC call to only 1 node in Azure Service Fabric

Tags: azure-service-fabric

When I make an RPC (service remoting) call to a service that is deployed on multiple nodes from another service in the same application, it appears to be going to all nodes at once.  I only want it to go to one each time the call is made.

Does Service Fabric have a way to do that? How can I leverage the built-in load balancing to control where the call goes to?

This deployed on a local cluster

Answer (score 1):

If your service is stateless and uses [Singleton partitioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-concepts-partitioning), calling an operation using the `ServiceProxy` will invoke the operation on one random service instance. Using SF [remoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-communication-remoting), you can't target a specific instance.

If your service is stateful, calling an operation using the `ServiceProxy` (created with a specific `ServicePartitionKey`) will invoke the operation on one of the replicas of your service, using the primary replica by default.